# how to make a for loop inside a workflow databricks

Tags: for-loop, databricks

In Databricks I have 2 Notebooks.  The first calls the second inside a For Loop, like this:

The Notebook 1_CIRCUITO at the end have this:

```
for doc in list_RREGA:
    dbutils.notebook.run("2_CIRCUITO",600,{"id_in":doc["id_in"]...)
```

So, the code execute the necessary number of times.

Now, I woul like to do it as a Workflow (1 task per Notebook) but I am not sure how do it, I don't see any function like a For Loop.
[image]

[image]

Can you give an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As rightly mentioed, as of date (`Feb '24`) there is no for loop (looping construct) in Databricks workflows. There could be few ways you could achieve / mock a looping strategy.

One way I could devise is you can try using widgets and another notebook which controls the flow:

`Notebook 1` -> `Controller_Notebook` (check for condition) -> `Notebook 2` (transfer control to Notebook 1)

The `Controller_Notebook` must have a while loop or a check on the list of parameters that is getting modified by `Notebook 1`

So if you have a list of parameters generated from `Notebook 1` then, you can place it as a json file in a temp location

```py
for key, val in enumerate([{"id_in": 1, "value_in": "a"}]):
    dbutils.fs.put(f"/tmp/location/{key}", json.dumps(val))
```

```py
# Assuming params from notebook 1 is stored in a temp location as a set of json files
params_from_notebook_1 = dbutils.fs.ls("/tmp/location/")

if params_from_notebook_1:
   # Get the current parameter
   curr_param = params_from_notebook_1[0]
   # Get the data corresponding to it
   data_from_param_file = 
json.loads(dbutils.fs.head(f"/tmp/location/{curr_param.name}"))
   # Remove the parameter file from the dbfs path
   dbutils.fs.rm(f"/tmp/location/{curr_param.name}")

   # Call Notebook 2 with the data fetched which has the current set of parameters
   dbutils.notebook.run("<Notebook 2>", 600, data_from_param_file)

   # Call `Controller_Notebook` again to loop through the rest of the params
   dbutils.notebook.run("<Controller_Notebook>", 600)
```

You can fetch the parameters required to run the second notebook using the `getArgument` method:

```py
id_in = getArgument("id_in")
value = getArgument("value")
```

There could be other ways, but hopefully Databricks must come up with a support on the looping construct.